# Masonite - TypeError > encoding without a string argument

Tags: python, frameworks, masonite

Whenever I render a view, the error

> encoding without a string argument`

is being thrown. This is my controller method:

```
def show(self, Application):
    view('welcome', {'app': Application})
```

Comment: to documentation common questions or problems for the Masonite framework. StackOverflow also explicitly promotes asking and answering your own question in order to do exactly this. So why do you downvote? https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ 

"To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged." from the StackOverflow blog itself

Edit: The person I was responding to deleted their comment

Comment: Alright :) My point was you were answering to yourself in the third-person, which is very weird. Retracted the close

Comment: Looks slightly less weird I thought lol :) As long as the answer answers the question I suppose.

Comment: and that blog points to an example question he answers himself which is questioned and answered in the third person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is being thrown because your view is not returning anything. Your view should always have a return in it because Masonite needs to know what you want to display.

You can fix this error by returning the view:

```
def show(self, Application):
    return view('welcome', {'app': Application})
```